# Bridging Knime, Keras and DL4J – Exceptions when loading h5 model

Tags: keras, deeplearning4j, knime, dl4j

I’m working on a project which needs to train a DNN and then run the trained model in a Java environment. As the training data requires a lot of manipulation I’ve used Knime and its Keras libraries to do most of the work, and I’m exported the trained model to a Keras h5 file which can be loaded into DL4J (I’m using Knime Keras Integration 4.1.0v201911171432 and DL4J 1.0.0-beta6).

The modelling is ongoing, but for a POC I’ve created a network by chaining the following nodes:

- Keras Input Layer (shape 144)
- Keras Dense Layer (units 500)
- Keras Dense Layer (units 500)
- Keras Dense Layer (units 1)
- Keras Set Output Layers (single output shape [1] pointing to the last layer)

This then gets trained and outputted with a “Keras Network Writer” node which writes a .h5 file.

In Java I have includes the following dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And run the following code:

```
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport;
…
ComputationGraph model = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights("2x2x2keras.h5");
```

Which returns the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: network has no outputs. Use .setOutput(String...) to specify (and give an ordering to) the output vertices, or use allowNoOutputs(true) to disable this check
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration.validate(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:375) ~[deeplearning4j-nn-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration$GraphBuilder.build(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:1197) ~[deeplearning4j-nn-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel.getComputationGraphConfiguration(KerasModel.java:394) ~[deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel.getComputationGraph(KerasModel.java:415) ~[deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel.getComputationGraph(KerasModel.java:404) ~[deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:173) ~[deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-beta6.jar:na]
    at dev.aisandbox.tftest.TFRunner.run(TFRunner.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
```

As this is the first time I’ve tried using Knime to manage my dataflow, I can’t be certain if the issues is with the file (being created in Knime) or the code loading it (into DL4J+Java). I’m assuming the comment about setOutput is intended for when you are creating the network with a python script, but can’t see anyway to set allowNoOutputs when KerasModelImport only has static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Keras model a Sequential? or a Model?  If it's a Sequential use `KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights()` instead.

Comment: Like you, I assumed that it would be a sequential model (as there is a sequence of layers with a single output); but when using importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights I got: InvalidKerasConfigurationException: Model class name must be Sequential (found Model). For more information, see http://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-overview

Answer (score 0):

You can try [use Deep Java Library](https://djl.ai). Here is document about [how to load Keras model into DJL](https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/docs/tensorflow/how_to_import_keras_models_in_DJL.md).

And you can find example project [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/tree/master/covid19-detection).